# How to read image file stored in internal memory?

Tags: android, image

In my android application I an storing an image file in internal memory using below code-

```
FileOutputStream fos = con.openFileOutput(fileName, con.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(baf.toByteArray()); // baf - ByteArrayBuffer
fos.close();
```

Can any one please help me to read this image file from internal display it in an activty?

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
File filePath = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
```

In the above snippet `R.id.image` is id of `ImageView` somewhere in your layout. `fileName` is a `String` containing name of the file you used in `openFileOutput` call.

Comment: Any way to see the file in eclipse? Through DDMS or something?

Comment: @Haraldo I'm not completely sure, but those files might be visible in DDMS if you have a rooted device.

Comment: @KonstantinBurov I figured it out. You can do it from withing DDMS. You look under file explorer data/data/your app/files. You can then pull the file from the device and save it on your computer.