# read/write image file in java on android platform

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

How do i read an image file and display that image in java onto the android platform. I understand i need to use intents and activities, but i'm not sure how to do it.

Basically i want to make an app on android that reads an image file and then write/display it. This can be done using intents and activities. When the user clicks on the read button, the image file gets read, and then when the user clicks on the write button the image gets displayed.

I'm not sure how to read an image file and then to display that image onto the android platform.

Comment: Do you want to read an image file and then display that image file?

Comment: Have a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802695/how-to-read-image-file-stored-in-internal-memory

Comment: @shadmazumder yes exactly! Writing it in java and then displaying it on the android platform