# Should I use /res/drawable or I have to store images in my internal storage?

Tags: android

I'm making an app that shows images in a ImageView.

I have the images that I want to show and them won't change in runtime but there a lot of them (400+/-). And I don't know if I can use directly from the folder /res/drawable or if I have to store them in the internal storage.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be stored in your `internal memory` because `res/drawable` are used to scale images that you implemented in your `Views/layouts` to be compatible with different **DPI** screens devices.

Since it is just an Image you want to show in your `ImageView` you really don't need to scale it, so internal storage is a way to go.

Comment: Ok, so the way is: First, I have to create a folder with my images in the internal storage and then I take the URL of the image and convert into Bitmap. Is it right? Can I use this answer [link](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-images-to-internal-memory-in-android) as example ?

Comment: @user3866898 right2x. you need to create a folder and read it from your internal storage.

Comment: You can follow this link on how to read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802695/how-to-read-image-file-stored-in-internal-memory